# Blob at 'image display' item APEX 5

Tags: oracle, blob, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a table with column type of blob,id and mime_type. i create a 'display image' item and try to cascade it from another text field but without submitting page.No success at all.   i work at apex 5.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question means, perhaps create an example on apex.oracle.com and/or look at the packaged sample applications

Comment: i have a 'display image' item (p1_image) which take value from a table with blobs. it cascaded from item at same page, lets say p1_design. So far, all works fine. I want to refresh p1 image when p1_design change but without submit page. Thats my problem.

Comment: This you? https://community.oracle.com/thread/3999740 If not, it has a suggested solution.

Comment: Yep, thats me..